# Illustrator: Is it possible to record an action that only changes the Stroke Width and nothing else?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, actions

[image: Adobe Illustrator "Actions" tab. 8pt Stroke is selected, with a dropdown showing further "Set Stroke" options. "Weight: 8pt" is marked as "I only need this one", while "Cap: Butt Cap; Miter Limit: 10; Join: Miter Join; Dashed Line(s): 0; Dash Adjustment: No; and Alignment: Center" are marked "These are automatically added during recording of action".]

I am currently recording actions for stuff that I do very frequently. One of the things I do a lot is changing the stroke width and changing the stroke alignment. However, when I record an action to set the stroke weight, the action also records the attributes for other things like Alignment and Cap style.

Is it possible to record only the changing of stroke width and leave everything else alone? I really need everything else to stay the same, especially the alignment.

I tried selecting and deleting them on the actions tab but nothing happens.

Comment: Not that i know, but i would need to test a few ideas. There is a chance that if you select multiple strokes with different settings that it would record correctly. But it can be scripted.